# Different durations for start and end of transitions?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.circle {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
 }

.box:hover + .circle {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
 </body>
```

Here, when I hover over `.box`, `.circle` fades in in 0.5s.

Now when I move my cursor away from `.box`, I want `.circle` to fade out at a different speed (say, 1s). How to make it happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the off duration on the non-hover state, and the on duration on the hover.

That is because once you hover, the `:hover` properties take precedence (*assuming your selectors are correctly specified*), so the duration you have for hover will apply. 
Once you hover off, the properties set on the normal element apply.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
.circle {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease;
}
    
.box:hover + .circle {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration:0.5s
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```